# All plugins deactivated. What could cause this?

Tags: plugins, wp-cli, deactivated-plugin

I have an AWS server running four WordPress sites.  All plugins have been deactivated on one of the sites and I cannot enable them.

When I try enabling them in bulk, or individually, there is no error and it even says "Plugin activated.", but they are not.

I have tried changing the ACLs temporarily, so that the webserver has full access.  I have tried moving directories of plugins that have been recently updated, but nothing works.

I have found that UpdraftPlus backups stopped being produced by this site and a similarly configured one (similar custom-made theme and nearly the same plugins) two days ago.

Also, I have noticed that WP-CLI has not been working properly with these two similar sites over the last couple of days.

I don't know what else to say.  I'm completely stumped.

What can I do about this?

Comment: Can you verify that the database user has add/update permissions for the WordPress database? Are you still able to add posts and other content?

Comment: @boscho Hi, thanks.  I made a test post and it showed up fine.  I have added some more information to the question.

Comment: Hrm... I have to admit I'm not sure as to what could be happening, here. But a couple of other steps towards troubleshooting the issue: you mention that no errors are displayed - do you have [`WP_DEBUG`](https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG) enabled in your `wp-config.php` file (and PHP set to display errors)? What do you get when you query your database with `SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'active_plugins';`?

Comment: Do you have APC object caching enabled?